# How to run multiple queries in single statement

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

This is my SQL code, a simple transaction. When i run it on phpmyadmin it's work well.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT received_money FROM bank_accounts WHERE `uuid` = "2eaef3e4-eeb6-41f7-9ecf-5d503465baba";
UPDATE bank_accounts SET received_money = 0 WHERE `uuid` = "2eaef3e4-eeb6-41f7-9ecf-5d503465baba";
COMMIT;
```

But i want to use this sql code directly in my Java code:

```
String sql = "START TRANSACTION;\n" +
            "SELECT placed_money FROM bank_accounts WHERE uuid = \"" + uuid + "\";\n" +
            "UPDATE bank_accounts SET placed_money = 0 WHERE uuid = \"" + uuid + "\";\n" +
            "COMMIT;";
Connection connection = connect();
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

But every time i have this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT received_money FROM bank_accounts WHERE `uuid` = "2eaef3e4-eeb6-41f7-9ecf' at line 2
```

Comment: show us how you defined and set the variable sql

Comment: Sorry I just added it

Comment: use instead \"  a single quote and also loo urgently for prepared statements

Comment: I have the same error with simple quote

Comment: You should not call `start transaction` and `commit transaction` in JDBC. You need to disable auto-commit mode (`Connection.setAutoCommit(false)`), and commit using `Connection.commit()`. Also JDBC is not designed for executing multiple statements like this, you should execute them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a multiple queries.

so you need a connection string that allows that

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///test?allowMultiQueries=true";
```

Further remove all \ n and as i said in the comment replace "

```
String sql = "START TRANSACTION;" +
        "SELECT placed_money FROM bank_accounts WHERE uuid = '" + uuid + "';" +
        "UPDATE bank_accounts SET placed_money = 0 WHERE uuid = '" + uuid + "';" +
        "COMMIT;";
```

Comment: It's work I don't have the same error anymore.
But i have "ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data."
Have you an idea ?